# How to pass mock object to unit test for custom simple_tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pytest

I have a custom simple_tag I've defined as follows:

```
@register.simple_tag
# usage: {% get_contact_preference_string user %}
def get_contact_preference_string(user):
    if user.contact_choice == 'C':
       return '{} prefers phone calls.'.format(user.first_name)
    # method continues
```

And a template which is correctly loading the tag & using it.

However, I'm struggling to pass a mock user to it in unit tests. Here's how I'm trying to write the test:

```
def test_get_contact_preference_string_returns_correctly_formatted_content(self):
    test_customer = Customer.objects.create('tfirst', 'C')
    template_to_render = Template(
        '{% load contact_preference_helpers %}'
        '{% get_contact_preference_string test_customer %}'
    )

    rendered = template_to_render.render(test_customer)
    expected = 'tfirst prefers phone calls.'

    self.assertEqual(rendered, expected)
```

It is raising `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contact_choice'` on hitting `render(test_customer)`, so I know I'm not passing the mock object in correctly. I have also tried passing `{'user': test_customer}` to no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a [`Context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context) instance to render the template. Try

```
from django.template import Context, Template

...

test_customer = Customer.objects.create('tfirst', 'C')
template_to_render = Template(
    '{% load contact_preference_helpers %}'
    '{% get_contact_preference_string test_customer %}'
)
ctx = Context({'test_customer': test_customer})
rendered = template_to_render.render(ctx)
```